# Not able to write in json format as desired using python

Tags: python, json

I have a csv file whose contents looks like below :

```
id,first_name,last_name
1,Sheilah,Gillham
2,Wallace,Kaas
```

and I want the output of this csv in the below json format:

```
{
'test_pipeline': 
           {'id': '1',
            'first_name': 'Sheilah',
            'last_name': 'Gillham'
 }
}
{
'test_pipeline': 
           {'id': '2',
            'first_name': 'Wallace',
            'last_name': 'Kaas'
 }
}
```

I have written the below python code to achieve the above output :

```
import json
import csv
# Creating a prototype of our final document
output = {'test_pipeline': {}}
# Opening the file
with open('MOCK_DATA.csv') as csv_file:

# Looping through each value of csv
    for i in csv.DictReader(csv_file):

# Adding the values in as json 
        output['test_pipeline'].update({
        
            'id': i['id'],
            'first_name' : i['first_name'],
            'last_name' : i['last_name']
            )}
       print(output)

# Dumping into Json
with open('mock_data.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(output,fout,indent=4)
```

But the problem is that it is printing the output correctly in console but while writing it into the mock_data.json file, it is only writing the last json not the full json as shown below :

```
{
'test_pipeline': 
           {'id': '2',
            'first_name': 'Wallace',
            'last_name': 'Kaas'
 }
}
```

Can someone please guide me how to print the whole json in mock_data.json file.

Comment: You need to use a list to hold the different entries instead of updating the same dictionary.

Comment: the JSON you've posted is not correct. Please edit and correct the JSON format. You can validate your JSON here https://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a list, to store the dictionaries.

Try this:

```
import json
import csv

output = []
with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    for i in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
        output.append(
            {
                'test_pipeline': 
                    {
                        'id': i['id'],
                        'first_name': i['first_name'],
                        'last_name': i['last_name'],
                    }
            }
        )
        print(output)

with open('mock_data.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(output, fout, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "test_pipeline": {
            "id": "1",
            "first_name": "Sheilah",
            "last_name": "Gillham"
        }
    },
    {
        "test_pipeline": {
            "id": "2",
            "first_name": "Wallace",
            "last_name": "Kaas"
        }
    }
]
```